# Swipe element down and up to delete/remove element using hammer.js and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I'm trying to swipe an element up/down to delete it.

I am using hammer.js and jQuery.

So far I can delete the element using swipe `left/right` which works fine.

But I need to achieve the exact same thing using swipe  `up/down`.

I have created this working example here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJPPyB

click on the button and an element will appear and then Swipe left/right to delete it.

With the code above, I tried the followings but it doesn't work as expected:

```
$toast.animate({ top: event.deltaX, opacity: opacityPercent }, { duration: 50, queue: false, specialEasing: 'easeOutQuad' });
```

and

```
              $toast
                  .removeClass('panning')
                  .animate({ bottom: 0, opacity: 1 }, {
                      duration: 300,
                      specialEasing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      queue: false
                  });
```

Can someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

When I change this:

```
 hammerHandler.on('pan', function (event) {
```

To this:

```
hammerHandler.on('pandow', function (event) {
```

I can move the element when I pandown but I dont know why it is very wonky!

This is how I swipe down now but it somtimes freezes the whole page and I dont undertand why!

```
 hammerHandler.on('pandown', function (event) {
      // Change toast state
      $toast.addClass('panning');

      var opacityPercent = 1 - Math.abs(event.deltaX / activationDistance);
      if (opacityPercent < 0)
          opacityPercent = 0;



      $toast.animate({ marginBottom: event.deltaX, opacity: opacityPercent }, { duration: 50, queue: false, specialEasing: 'easeOutQuad' });
  });
```

Comment: It's wonky because it overlaps with the scroll event. You need to tell the browser not to listen for scroll events from that element. [This](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1169) might help. If not, search for similar ones. Also note the [tip on hammer](https://hammerjs.github.io/tips/) page: try to avoid vertical pan/swipe.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, You see, I don't have that scroll event issue. because I'm trying to use this code in a hybrid mobile app and the whole page (body) in the mobile app is scroll hidden. By wonky I meant it is not reacting the way it should with pendown compared with pan left/right.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, also the hammer tip that says:  try to avoid vertical pan/swipe. seems to be saying that because of older browsers if I'm not mistaken... But I am using this in modern browsers and also in a hybrid app.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPM6172J22g) might be relevant. You'll probably have better results using a [passive touch listener](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md). See here [how to identify listeners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-D_3yx_KVI) blocking scrolling.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, why passive touch listener?! as I said, my issue is not the scrolling!